# What are the minimum safe conditions for running a small dye sublimation heat press?

Tags: print-production

I work in an office that has recently purchased an 8.5x11" Sawgrass dye sub printer, which we're using with a 14x14" clamshell heat press and a mug press.

I am aware that some of the vaporized ink escapes when you open the press after use, and that it's probably not great to breathe it.

I can't find an MSDS from Sawgrass or basically anywhere, and anything I do find mentions nothing about ventilation or the vapor, only the room-temperature inks.

Comment: [Contacting Sawgrass](https://www.sawgrassink.com/Special-Pages/Contact-Sawgrass.aspx) would seem like the first step.

Answer (score 4):

MSDS 
https://www.nwgraphic.com/sads/sawgrass/053-SubliJet-Cyan.pdf
Reveals no known health hazard

If you are smelling fumes, I suggest installing a hood over the printer. Such a hood can be an ordinary vent hood of the type used over the burners of a household stove/range.

Dye sublimation usually works by supplying a ribbon impregnated with colored wax. Heat is applied causing the wax to vaporize. The wax vapor migrates into the porous paper. The wax vapor immediately cools returning the wax to a solid.

Sublimation is the process of changing states, i.e. solid to vapor, skipping the liquid stage. As an example, dry ice is solid carbon dioxide. As its temperature elevates, it changes to a gas skipping the liquid state.